# Objective-C Class definitions

Tags: objective-c, class, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to alter the definition of a class in Objective-C?

For example, I have a function that creates objects (bullets), and those bullets are all the same.  However, if given an event, say a power-up, I want to alter those bullets.  In either size, or color, or what-have-you.

In my code, I have

```
 playerBullet = [[PlayerBullet alloc] init];
```

But that always initializes the new bullet, regardless of 'power-up', as  the standard, template bullet.

Is there a way that I adjust the class definition such that all new allocations of the PlayerBullet class come with the new value?

```
PlayerBullet.setProjectileColor:@"red";
```

Or is this approach a bad one?

Comment: The approach you're suggesting doesn't make sense. Instead, give your Bullet object as many @property values as it needs, and alter their properties as needed.

Comment: That is essentially what I'm doing.  But my issue is that when I an update function, that updates every second, and gameLogic elsewhere dictates if I get a 'power-up'.  So in that update 'loop', I'm trying to avoid a bunch of if-else-if-else statements. 

So I thought if I could change the class definition, or the blueprint elsewhere, then I could just keep generating the same objects, but using a new blueprint.

Comment: If your property values are intended to be dynamic, just provide a custom reader method for them that returns the right value. If you're accessing your properties correctly (i.e., you're referring to `[object propertyname]` and **not** `object->propertyname` then you will let the object manage itself -- which is the proper object oriented design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question as asked is `No`. However, what you are trying to do is very easily achievable with the proper design.

You should create a customer initialization method in your `PlayerBullet` class that takes an argument.

```
- (id) initWithProjectileColor:(NSString*)color 
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.projectileColor = color;
    }
    return self;
}
```

So you could make a method and then call something like:

```
[[PlayerBullet alloc] initWithProjectileColor:@"red"];
```

Alternatively, you could create public properties and set them after creating a "blank" projectile.

Answer (score 1):

call `[[PlayerBullet alloc] initWithColor:@"red"]` where you need it:

```
-(id) initWithColor:(NSString*) color{
    self = [self init];
    [self setProjecticeColor:colour];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this automatically. You could do it yourself with something like this. (Memory management not included.)

```
static NSString *DefaultProjectileColor = @"black";

+(void) setDefaultProjectileColor:(NSString *)color {
    DefaultProjectileColor = color;
}

+(NSString *) defaultProjectileColor {
    return DefaultProjectileColor;
}

-(id) init {
    ...
    self.projectileColor = [PlayerBullet defaultProjectileColor];
    ...
}

-(void) gotPowerUp {
    ...
    [PlayerBullet setDefaultProjectileColor:@"red"];
    ...
}
```